# Create a folder on a share each time a workstation joins the server 2012 domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows

I'm trying to automate the creation and deletion of a folder each time a computer is added or removed from the domain.

When a computer joins a domain, I'd like folder w/ %computername% to be created.
When a computer is removed from a domain, I'd like folder %computername% deleted from the domain.

One thing that I'm trying is to create a task in Task Scheduler, that begins the task "On an Event". That way I can check for the event when a computer joins/removes a domain, and then create or delete accordingly. Is there a way for the task to parse the eventlog so I can extract the computer name from it when the task is run?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Remote resources are generally user oriented, so it sounds like you are not taking the best approach.  Without further info it is impossible to say that for sure though.

Comment: What is this folder used for? Take a step back and explain your larger problem that you're trying to solve, there may be a better way.